# Idea of how to make a slider of images

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm new with CSS, HTML, Javascript.
What I'm trying to do, is a slider of images, when you click lelft/right arrow to go the prev/next imagine.

I made at this moment something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/186U6.png

What I want to do is something like this: https://i.imgur.com/JVAvr62.mp4

EDIT: I've added snippet. Hope now is alright!

```js
function prev() {
    //do_something..
}

function next() {
    //do_something..
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet');

.content {
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out,margin .3s ease-in-out;
    padding-top: 35px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 101px);
    z-index: 800;
}

.header_title {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.item_ep {
    margin-right: 18px;
}

.info_ep {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.item_ep .info_ep .season {
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #b3b3b3;
}

.item_ep .info_ep .title_ep {
    color: #808080;
}

.pull-right {
    float:right;
}

.title_header {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css?">
  
  <div class="content">
            <div class="header_title">
                <span class="title_header">Latest episodes</span>
                <!-- scroll -->
                <div class="scroll_arrows pull-right">
                    <a class="prev btn" onclick="prev()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <a class="next btn" onclick="next()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slider">
                <div id="1" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/wmOuYyqVaczBLXxQNFSaRfAUgPz.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 5, Episode 9</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Lucifer</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="2" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/3mBZwTEuN2CejVTeZqVfy2Kx5dY.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 10, Episode 15</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Ragnarok</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="1" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/wmOuYyqVaczBLXxQNFSaRfAUgPz.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 5, Episode 9</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Lucifer</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="2" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/3mBZwTEuN2CejVTeZqVfy2Kx5dY.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 10, Episode 15</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Ragnarok</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="1" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/wmOuYyqVaczBLXxQNFSaRfAUgPz.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 5, Episode 9</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Lucifer</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="2" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/3mBZwTEuN2CejVTeZqVfy2Kx5dY.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 10, Episode 15</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Ragnarok</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="1" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/wmOuYyqVaczBLXxQNFSaRfAUgPz.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 5, Episode 9</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Lucifer</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="2" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/3mBZwTEuN2CejVTeZqVfy2Kx5dY.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 10, Episode 15</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Ragnarok</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="2" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/3mBZwTEuN2CejVTeZqVfy2Kx5dY.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 10, Episode 15</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Ragnarok</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="2" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/3mBZwTEuN2CejVTeZqVfy2Kx5dY.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 10, Episode 15</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Ragnarok</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="2" class="item_ep">
                    <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/3mBZwTEuN2CejVTeZqVfy2Kx5dY.jpg" class="img_ep">
                    <div class="info_ep">
                        <span class="season">Season 10, Episode 15</span><br>
                        <span class="title_ep">Ragnarok</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try to fit your code to the snippet. [Here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) is some info about snippets.

Comment: What have you tried? This is not how StackOverflow works. Nobody will write an application for you. Take a Look at the guidelines.

Comment: For such sliders it's a good idea to use some specific libraries like [this](https://splidejs.com/getting-started/). If you already use one tell which one is it or just see their doc to know how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post, I have fitted the code to snippet. @NICO, I don't want to write someone a code for my app, I just wanted to know an Idea like the title says. BTW, I'm using Laravel, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

What is your question?

The `.slider` class has `flex-wrap: wrap;`, so it is wrapping items to the next line. You'll want `flex-wrap: nowrap;`.

You may want some JavaScript handling to determine which items to display.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post because I forgot to put nowrap like  you said, i changed the script after and it was an old CSS script. So basically when you click the ">" or "<" to go to the next/prev image, something like this must happend: https://i.imgur.com/JVAvr62.mp4